# Matrix valued Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Does anyone have any good reference of a book that talks about matrix valued Hilbert spaces? I am interested in Sobolev spaces and how the gradient and divergence work in these type of spaces.